# how to remove array index out of bound error in matlab

Tags: matlab

here is my code where i have one error regarding array index out out of bound. plzz help me to rectify it

```
I = imread('E:\degraded images\village.jpg');
imshow(I)


I = im2double(I);
I = log(1 + I);

M = 2*size(I,1) + 1;
N = 2*size(I,2) + 1;

sigma = 10;

[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:N,1:M);
centerX = ceil(N/2);
centerY = ceil(M/2);
gaussianNumerator = (X - centerX).^2 + (Y - centerY).^2;
H = exp(-gaussianNumerator./(2*sigma.^2));
H = 1 - H;

imshow(H,'InitialMagnification',25)

H = fftshift(H);

If = fft2(I, M, N);
Iout = real(ifft2(H.*If)); ** here the code has error . ??? Error using ==> times Number of array dimensions must match for binary array op.**
```

Comment: Probably H and If are not the correct dimensions. Add size(H) and size(If) right before the line that produces the error to see what their sizes are first.

Comment: yes size(h)=(617*819) and size(If)= (617*819*3) .. how to make them same

Answer (score 0):

`H` is 2-D while `If` is 3-D. You can use `repmat` with `H` or subset `If`. I don't know which one is correct for your situation. For instance,

```
rempat( H, [1, 1, 3 ] ) .* If;
```

or

```
H .* If(:,:,ind);  % ind is the index of the 2-D array you want to subset
```

Comment: i want to change size of H from 2d to 3d

Comment: @sheelumishra Then use `repmat` as in the first example.